# "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

i need show all category in view . i used this code for show all :

Category = Tabel name of Database

```
public List<Category> GetAllCategory()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
```

/****************************************/

```
public ActionResult ListCategory()
    {
        return View(_CategoryService.GetAllCategory());
    }
```

/*****************************************/

i create model `CategoryModel` .

```
 public class CategoryModel 
{
    [Display(Name ="کد دسته")]
    public int CatID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = " نام دسته")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = " سر دسته")]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

/**********************************/

and in view i use this :

```
@model IEnumerable<Amene.Models.CategoryModel>
```

but it show me this error :

> > The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DA.Data.DB.Category]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Amene.Models.CategoryModel]'.

o know i must user table name in view `Category` but i need use `CategoryModel` .

how can i do this ?

Comment: Your method returns `List<Category>` and `Category` is not the same as `CategoryModel` If you want `CategoryModel`, then generate a collection of that type.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can i do this ?

Comment: `_CategoryService.GetAllCategory().Select(x => new CategoryModel { CatID = x.CatID, CategoryName = x.CategoryName, .... })` assuming the property names of `Category` are the same as the property names of `CategoryModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke this problem not have any way without this ?

Comment: Of course not. You view expects `IEnumerable<CategoryModel>` so you need to give it `IEnumerable<CategoryModel>`